Using Fredholm Alternative theorem to solve PDEs
I am trying to solve a coupled PDE system using the perturbation theorem, where parameter $\epsilon$ is small and all the variables are expanded in even powers of $\epsilon$. The set of equations and the boundary conditions are the following

The text I am reading presents the solutions as

Using the first-order equations $\epsilon=0$, I get Eq. 3.11. However, I cannot drive Eq. 3.11 and 3.12. The text mentions that Fredholm alternative theory can be used to drive these equations. I spent some time to read about this theorem, and if I understood it correctly it says a solvability condition can be find by calculating an integral
$\int_{H-h/2}^{H+h/2} dy f(x,y) u_0 =0.$
However, I used $u_0$ from Eq. 3.11. Using Eq.3.4 for the second order in $\epsilon$ I decided that $f(x,y)= \partial_x p_0 -\partial_x^2 u_0$. But this does not give me Eq. 3.12.
Note: I am not sure if the above equation is equivalent to Fredholm theorem, I am just guessing.
I appreciate it if someone could show me how to use the Fredholm alternative theorem to get Eqs. 3.12 and 3.13.
I read this post and tried to do the same for my equations but still don't get the solvability condition 3.12. Could someone please help? Here is what I have done
the equation governing $u_0$ read ($\epsilon =0$ in 3.4)
$\partial_y^2 u_0=0.$
Solving equations and using the BCs gives us the value for $p_0=-2 \partial^2_x u_0$ and $v_0=\partial_t H(x,t)$.
Now, the 3.4 in the next order reads
$\partial_y^2 u_1 = -\partial_x p_0 + \partial^2_x u_0$.
The solvability condition as explained in enter link description here reads
$\int_{H-h/2}^{H+h/2} (-\partial_x p_0 + \partial^2_x u_0) u_0 =0$
this can be simplified to
$\int_{H-h/2}^{H+h/2} (3 \partial^2_x u_0) u_0 =0$
Using 3.11 as $u_0$ and taking the integral does not give us 3.12!
I am very confused with this and very much appreciate if some one could help.

I gave (what I consider) a fairly complete answer on the topic of solvability conditions and the Fredholm alternative here, though your problem here seems to be more difficult than the one I answered. Go through it, see if you can apply it to your problem above and if you have any questions after just comment below.

@MatthewCassell could you please explain how you found the adjoint (Eq. 6)?

If you are referring to equation $6$ in the link I provided in my previous comment, finding the adjoint comes from using integration by parts and assuming the boundary conditions, which weren't given in the question, make the evaluated terms vanish.

Thanks, but I don't see how using Eq. 5 in the link and the integration by part leads to equation 6. There is also a derivative with respect to t and a constant 1 which cannot be transferred to integration by part. @MatthewCassell

DoI need to combine the equations and get one equation? @MatthewCassell

@MatthewCassell the operator has a second order derivative on x, so after two integrations by parts, there shouldn't be a negative sign? I cannot figure out where the negative sign comes from. Could you please help?

I think you might be confused by the fact I stated the inner product there $\langle A, B \rangle$ has measure $dx$ because you don't seem to have calculated the $dy$ and $dt$ integrals. In the context of the post $dx$ is just a place holder for the measures $dy$ and $dt$ as you have to integrate with respect to all the coordinates that appear in the leading order equation to compute the adjoint i.e in full, the inner product is $\langle A, B \rangle = \int A \bar{B} dx dy dt$. Now apply integration by parts on each term and assume each evaluated quantity vanishes.
